# How to create an associate array with value of a list of items in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create such a associated array in bash:

```py
myarr = {
    'key1' : ["command_name", "command name with arguments"],
    'key2' : ["command_name", "command name with arguments"],
}
```

The reason I want to do the above is so that I can pass a key to the script and then do something like this:

- Use the key to index into the associative array
- Use some tool to check whether the application given by `command_name` is open
- If the window is not open, lunch the application given by `command name with arguments`

Such a task is trivial in a popular programming language, but it doesn't seem to be as trivial in bash.

**EDIT**

I'd like to be able to create something like this:

```sh
declare -A array=(
    [c]=("code" "code")
    [e]=("dolphin" "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE dolphin")
    [n]=("nvim" "kitty nvim")
)
```

Comment: Do you want to create the associative array by parsing a JSON file?

Comment: The value needs to be just a scalar (string). You could create for each of your "lists" a separate array variable, store the name of the variable with each key, and use indirect referencing to access the list data. It's clumsy - bash is not really made for this. Is there a reason why you want to use bash?

Comment: Why not using two associative arrays, one for the command names and the other for the arguments? But storing the arguments in one single element is not recommended. A better option would probably to use one associative array for the command names, indexed by your keys, and as many indexed arrays as you have keys, named as the keys (if they are valid names for bash variables) and access them either with a nameref or an indirection. This way you could call your commands with `declare -n args="$key"; ${commands["$key"]} "${args[@]}"`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, can you give an example of how to do it?

Comment: @user1934428, I want to configure i3 window manager. It is easier to use bash for that than other programming languages.

Comment: please update the question with what you expect the `bash` array to look like; at this point it looks (to me) like you want to create an array of arrays ... doable but a bit more complicated than a 'normal' array

Comment: @markp-fuso, see update

Comment: Bash does not support array values being anything but a string. That said, I did work around that in `declarative.bash` if you want to find an example. Search for `_declarative_assertions_for_var` inside its source, there's a fair bit of care taken around eval safety.

Comment: This does not mean that you have to write **everything** in bash. Use a convenient language of your choice to calculate the configuration parameter(s), and then use bash to actually invoke the configuration program of your window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: take comments into account and replace now useless arrays by scalar strings.

As you want to set bash variables in the command's context we cannot execute them with `"$cmd"`, this would not work for variable assignments. The following uses `eval`, which is [extremely risky](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), especially if you do not fully control the inputs. A better solution, but more complicated, would be to use other variables for the execution environment, declare functions to limit the scope of variables and/or restore them afterwards, use `eval` only in last resort and only after sanitizing its parameters (`printf '%q'`)... Anyway, you have been warned.

Storing bash commands and their arguments in variables is [not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). But if you really need this it would be better to store the command names and the full commands in 2 different variables. They could be associative arrays or, if your bash is recent enough and supports namerefs, scalar variables named from your keys (if they are valid bash variable names).

Example where the key is stored in bash variable `k`, and the command is the second of your own example, plus some dummy arguments:

```sh
k="e"
# add a new command with key "$k"
declare -n cmd="${k}_cmd" lcmd="${k}_lcmd"
cmd="dolphin"
lcmd="XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE dolphin arg1 arg2 'arg 3'"
...
# launch command with key "$k"
declare -n cmd="${k}_cmd" lcmd="${k}_lcmd"
if not_running "$cmd"; then
  eval "$lcmd"
fi
```

Demo with key `foo`, command `printf` and arguments `'%s\n' 'a b' 'c d'`:

```sh
$ k="foo"
$ declare -n cmd="${k}_cmd" lcmd="${k}_lcmd"
$ cmd="printf"
$ lcmd="printf '%s\n' 'a b' 'c d'"
$ eval "$lcmd"
a b
c d
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I wanted to save the command along with its arguments in full is because of situations like this: I am using i3wm. I want dolphin file manager to be properly themed. To do this, I need to set the set `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` before calling the application. So, the command I end up running is: `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE dolphin ~/Downloads`.

Comment: `eval "${lcmd[@]}"` behaves **exactly** like `eval "${lcmd[*]}"`, which is to say, it has a number of surprising bugs. Consider `cmd=( printf ' - %s\n' "first element" "second element" )` -- this will be correctly executed with `"${cmd[@]}"`; I invite you to see for yourself what `eval "${cmd[@]}"` does.

Comment: ...the above is because `eval` combines all its arguments together into a single string to feed into the parser; so any quotes that were used to decide on the boundaries between `eval`'s arguments simply get thrown away without having any useful effect.

Comment: ...so if you're going to use `eval` to evaluate things you looked up via an associative array, you might as well store those things as strings in the first place -- because they'll be turned into strings before `eval` processes them no matter what.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right, of course. The first version of the question was not mentioning variables setting so my initial answer was not using `eval`. After this change I should have dropped the use of arrays.